# How to find $\ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit of the following expression:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}$$

As I plot this function, it seems that this goes to $1$. Is it correct?

Comment: nevermind, there's a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126099/how-do-i-take-the-limit-as-n-goes-to-infty-of-dfrac-sqrtn-logn?rq=1

Comment: Do you know the limit of $\dfrac{\log (n)}{n}$ as $n\longrightarrow +\infty$?

Comment: i think he got the answer

Comment: So in terms of big oh notation: log n= O(n) and $log n=O(\sqrt n) ?

Comment: Plots can be misleading when dealing with limiting behaviour of slowly-changing functions such as $\log n$ and $\sqrt{n}$.

Answer (score 4):

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log{\sqrt{n}}^2}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2\log\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt n}=2\times\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}=2\times0=0$

Comment: I don't follow the first step.  $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log^2 n}{n}}$ certainly, but where does the $\log 2n$ come from?

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\sqrt n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\log n}\times\sqrt{\log n}}{\sqrt n}=\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n\times \log n}{n}}=\sqrt{\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log 2n}{n}}$ Now this course? @Goos

Comment: $\log n \times \log n$ is not equal to $\log 2n$ though!

Comment: $\log 2n = \log n + \log 2$.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I had me confused. See now if is correct. @Goos

Comment: yep, looks good!  +1.